# rails view not rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

View:

```
<% form_tag(:action => 'create', :multipart => true) do %>
  Select CSV File:
  <%= file_field_tag 'data' %>
  <br/><br/>
  <%= submit_tag 'Upload' %>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
class UploadController < ApplicationController
  def index
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {render :layout => false}
    end
  end

  def create
    DataFile.save(params[:data])
    respond_to do |format|
      render :text => "File has been uploaded"
      # format.html { redirect_to :back }
    end
  end
end
```

When I go to upload/new nothing is rendered - just a blank page. If I put content in the view outside of the `form_tag` then it is rendered correctly.

Comment: Looks like you got the answer on your own! :)

Comment: Please don't edit your question to contain the answer. Accept the answer that solved your problem by clicking the checkmark beside it.

Comment: It was the only way i could show that i solved the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ERB in Rails 3, use an equals sign to output the contents of a block:

```
<%= form_tag :stuff do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```